# Two uiview not fitting for all screen with same size

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiscreen

I am new to iOS. I am learning my self. No resource are to clear my problem.

I have `two view` with `270 X 338`. that I have to keep in `Horizontally` in `Viewcontroller`. But, when I add some constraints it's not fitting for below 5s. I checked in simulator also in preview option.

When i use `autoresizing`, also it's not fitting for below 5s screen. Please help me with some idea. I need to do only in storyboard.

Thanks

I tried this tutorial [Here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/115440/auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-9-part-1-getting-started-2) but it din't help

This is my preview screen[image]

Edited:

[image]

Constraints for Back View;

[image]

Comment: show your view controller image

Comment: which constraints have you added in this two views?

Comment: @PiyushPatel  posted some tutorial link in above. They used some constraints ,that only i used

Comment: @DivyanshuSharma  i have added one image. in that when i tried to fit for all screen its not fitting well. in simulator below 5s its not fitting well

Comment: are u fixing the width and height of those view? that will make ur view doesnt fit, u should only use aspect ratio and 4-side constraint

Comment: @Tj3n  I added 1. `equally width` for 2 view. then for `first view` i added `Top, Left `constraints.Then for` second view` i added `right and top` constraints. At last i added `equal height` for `both views`. And for` first view` i added `nearest neighbour of right`

Comment: do you want your width to be compromised?

Comment: @EICaptain  I dont want to fill for whole screen i want it only half like my screen 6 size in my above image

Comment: @RahulPatel  .Compromised in the sense that??

Comment: I would suggest using UIStackedView for this which will help you to create two UIView of equal width and height.

Answer (score 3):

These steps will help you align two views.

- Add top, leading, and height for first and second views.
- Add trailing constraint from First view to Second view as 8.
- Add Equal Width for First view and SuperView and set its multiplier to 0.49* and constant as 0.
- Add Equal width for two views again by selecting two views.
- Finally update constraints the view will align for all sizes.
- - 0.49 will leave 8 points as trailing constraint.

**Constraints for First View**

[image]

**Constraints for Second View**

[image]

[image]

Edit :

For third step you can do by selecting first view and hold Control button and and move mouse to super view.

[image]

The selected view in the below image is the Superview
[image]

Comment: 3rd point is not clear for me. i select first view and tried to add equal widht. But that option is disabled. And what is that superview means??

Comment: Select First View and SuperView and add equal width constraint and select the constraint in size attributes, set multiplier of constraint to 0.49 instead of 1 and constant as 0. I have posted image for reference.

Comment: Or else you can do it by control + click form Firstview to SuperView which shows an action view select equal width in that

Comment: yes its clear about adding values. But superview is my second view are what??I am new to this. That why asking, does superview is my second view??

Comment: the background view(parentView) which is white color is the super view. The view at the top on the Document outline where you are adding two colored views as subview(child view)

Comment: no like my same image i have posted in my above post only getting. My uiview size is 180 X 225.

Comment: @Maddey i have added image for reference

Comment: @Rugmanhathan  Please see my updated post. I did all . But not able to get

Comment: set constant to 0 for proportional width. As the iphone's have different screen sizes it will adapt to those sizes using auotlayout. Also set multiplier to 0.465 for having leading 10 points.

Comment: s i set constan to zero only. But not able to get

Answer (score 1):

Use `leading`, `top` and `relative height` and `width` constraint that will solve your problem... set `relative height` and `width` in view with `autolayout` from below steps

1. Set equal height and width with superview.
2. Go to properties of constraint where you find a property multiplier in which set exact multiplier value which you want or which satisfy your constraint.
3. This will make height and width of view relative to superview that changes according to superview.

Comment: i am new to ios. Really dont know about to fix for leading top and relative hight and width.

Comment: Use this tutorial.... after completing this tutorial you will never stuck in any view related issue http://www.raywenderlich.com/115440/auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-9-part-1-getting-started-2

Comment: That tutorial only i followed to add  constraints for all uiview

Answer (score 1):

View 1

[image: View1]

View 2

[image: View2]

you can do it by adding contraints like this also